# Concatenate a range of a List<string>

Tags: c#, string, concatenation, aggregate

If I have a `List<string>`, and I want to create a single `string` from *all* elements in the list, I can use either `Join` or `Aggregate` like below to accomplish that.

```
var list = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
var concatAllByJoin = string.Join(string.Empty, list);
var concatAllByAggregate = list.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

Either will produce the string `ABCDE`.

What if I want to do the same, but only for a certain range in the list. Say, I want to concatenate items between indices 1 and 3 inclusive. In other words, I want the result to be `BCD`.

One approach I can think of is using `GetRange()` like so:

```
var concatRange = string.Join(string.Empty, list.GetRange(1, 3));
```

This obviously works, but the problem is data duplication. I'm interested in knowing if there's a way to do this without the duplication.

Comment: What do you mean by data duplication?

Comment: Are you using .NET Core 3 by any chance?

Comment: Doesn't `GetRange()` create a new list?

Comment: @maccettura no it's .NET regular framework. 4.7 to be exact.

Comment: `GetRange()` returns a shallow copy of a range of elements in the source `List<T>`.

Comment: `Enumerable.Distinct()` but depends whether you want to apply that before or after your range.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski still there are two copies. If I change a value at a certain index of the result of `GetRange()`, it doesn't change the original.

Comment: @Sach do you need to change the original? is that what your question is, 'How to i get a list of sub elements of a list as reference ?`

Comment: No, the question really is that how do you concat a list of strings without creating a secondary list in the process.

Comment: GetRange() creates a new list albeit a shallow copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this:

```
var concatRange = string.Join(string.Empty, list.Skip(1).Take(3));
```

you will **not** create another list instance. But for small sets I think you'll find the extra list is not as costly and probably much more efficient than the enumerators. Remember, the list elements only store *references*, so the string values themselves *are not copied* with either option.

Comment: This is probably what I was looking for. Yes I understand that I can use `GetRange()` as I'm not probably going to concat 100K items, was mostly interested to know if it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) for that

```cs
var list = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };

var builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    builder.Append(list[i]);
}

var concatRange = builder.ToString();
```

It doesn't create any copies of source list - you just access an elements by index and adding them to `StringBuilder`. 
You can also specify the maximum number of items (which can be stored in the memory allocated by the `StringBuilder` instance) by specifying `capacity` value, passed in constructor.

Performance benchmark in comparison with `Linq` solution. 
I don't think, that they are very accurate, because the source list is too small, but the performance difference is significant.

[image]